# tr class array for ajax post jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to fetch data from a mysql database using jquery ajax and php. I have
two row (tr) in a table and their class name is same. 
First row working fine. I can search product in mysql database and get return back price and sellprice value in inputs box. Issue is second row (tr) it doesn't send data to mysql database but its getting same input value like first row. I think need to create array in javascript to fetch data from database for each row (tr). Anyone can help me to solve this issue that would be appreciated. For better understand i'm posting images.

Now what im getting result image:
[Both row getting same input values and 2nd row not fetching data from db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGFPC.png)

Expected result image: [Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0exm.png)

```js
$(function(){ 
        $('.productdetail').delegate('.product,.price,.sellprice','keyup',function(){
       var tr = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
               var product = tr.find('.product').val();
                
                    $.ajax({  
                         url:"fetch.php",  
                         method:"post",  
                         data:{product:product},  
                         dataType:"text",  
                         success:function(data)  
                         {
                            var getarray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                            var price = getarray.price;
                            var sellprice = getarray.sellprice;
            
                            tr.find('.price').val(price);
                            tr.find('.sellprice').val(sellprice);
                            //$('#result').html(data);  
                            }
                        
                            });  
                    });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="productdetail">

    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Sell price</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="product" name="product[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="price" type="text" name="price[]"</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="sellprice" name="sellprice[]" /></td>
          </tr>
          
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="product" name="product[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="price" type="text" name="price[]"</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="sellprice" name="sellprice[]" /></td>
          </tr>
   </table>
```

im using json encode array to retrieve php data to javascript.

**fetch.php**

```
$product = strtolower($_POST["product"]);


require_once ('db.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbproduct WHERE product LIKE '$product'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {        {

            $array = array(
                'price' => $row["price"],
                'sellprice' => $row["sellprice"],
                );


            echo json_encode($array);

        }

    }
} else {
    echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbproduct` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `product` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `sellprice` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
);
```